# R: How to implement parallel processing when calculating polychoric correlation matrix?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, correlation

I am trying to implement parallel processing to speed up the calculation of a polychoric correlation matrix using the `hetcor()` function from the `polycor` package. Here's some example code with desired output:

```
set.seed(352)
toy <- 
  data.frame(A = sample(0:7), 
             B = sample(0:7), 
             C = sample(0:7)) %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = ordered)
toy
hetcor(toy, ML = FALSE, pd = TRUE)
```

So this takes a second or two already, but can take >20 minutes with my actual dataset. I know that the `parallel` package can utilize the 8 cores I have on my computer to make this faster. But I can not figure out how to implement it, or even where to start. Most of the examples I find online are using apply-style approaches, which seems different from what I'm trying to do (unless you're supposed to loop this process somehow, maybe with the `polychor()` function?).

Is there a generous soul that can show an example of how to use the `parallel` package to calculate polychoric correlation matrix from the `toy` data?

Comment: I think `parallel` is a great base-level package, but there are several others built onto it that make doing things in parallel a little easier. I'd look into `future` and `future.apply`, among many others. You might also consider `callr::r_bg`, which is a one-shot *"start a new R instance with a specific function"*.

Comment: But since you're trying to parallelize one function call, the way you can speed things up is to divide-and-conquer. I don't know that `polychor::hetcor` is set up to do that natively. (Not every problem makes it easy, tbh.)

Comment: Today, polychor::hetcor() has "parallel" parameter.